# Javascript: select property from object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a array of objects and I want to select a property of a certain object in that array. When I try the following code, it doesn't work, I don't get any value in the string:

```
var _string = teams[2].name;
```

Below the code of the array:

```
var teams = new Array (team1, team 2, team3);

var team1 = {
     name: "team 1",
     matches: 5 
}


var team2 = {
     name: "team 2",
     matches: 4 
}


var team3 = {
     name: "team 3",
     matches: 3 
}
```

Some help would be great :-)

Thanks

G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare your teams first and your array afterwards like this:

```
var team1 = {
     name: "team 1",
     matches: 5 
}

var team2 = {
     name: "team 2",
     matches: 4 
}

var team3 = {
     name: "team 3",
     matches: 3 
}

var teams = [team1, team2, team3];
```

Also note there is a space between `team` and `2` in your code which is incorrect.

Comment: Hi

Thank you, it was placing the declaration afterwards that did the trick :-)

G

Answer (score 0):

There is error `var teams = new Array (team1, team 2, team3);`and should be `var teams = new Array (team1, team2, team3);`

You add unnecessary space between `team` and `2` :)

Comment: Hi

you're correct, but to solve the problem I had to place declaration of the array afterwards :-)

G